# Why is there no collection about all mathematical theorems and open questions?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, online-resources

I really would like to have a giant math collection which is sorted according to the Mathematics Subject Classification, but with more then 3 levels, and it should contain all known theorems and also many current open questions.

Is there a good reason why one should not construct such an online collection of math theorems and open questions?

Comment: It would require an insane amount of work. I suppose people don't have enough time to do this, even collaboratively, and maintain it.

Comment: Are you aware that 10,000 papers of math research are published every year, Adam?

Comment: It'd be nice to have indeed. Wolfram is sort of trying to do this with their "computational knowledge" approach, and lately, they have tried to auto generate "interesting" theorems (on continuous fractions if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: I don't think there are actual reasons not to do it. But there are no resources to do it. For comparison, one thing of similar nature (but **much** smaller scale, and for a very specific, narrow subdomain) I'm aware of are so called "next generation" proofs of classification of finite simple groups - combined effort of dozens of people produced a body of results that together constitutes a proof, and later this work was "refactored" to streamline it and make it more systematic.

Comment: (cont.) It was a tremendous amount of work (revised version is few thousands pages), and I'd be shocked if it was even close to 1% of all the math there is to describe as you propose - even if we were to be extremely conservative as to what to include.

Comment: I agree, it would take a huge amout of work. And keep in mind that you can view every theorem from different perspectives and find different proofs. So perhaps you need totally different requirements. And while one may see a theorem as a corollary another one might see it the other way around.

Comment: @GerryMyerson there are many math papers with applications not including a new theorem. Also, I would assume that everyone who made a decent discovery would immediately want to add the result to this collection. I don't plan to do it by myself.

Comment: And there are many math papers with several new theorems, so it balances out. What would your collection do that Math Reviews doesn't?

Comment: It's called the internet.

Answer (score 3):

You do realize how big of a topic math is right? This book, if written in a normal font, just the theorems would take over 1,000 pages. Open questions are literally infinite, it's just whether or not anyone has asked them. There are apparently over 100,000 papers published<sup>[[1]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233984/how-many-papers-are-posted-a-year?noredirect=1#comment578936_233984)</sup> in the year 2013. If you insist the best there likely is is either the internet or a math dictionary. (I personally like the Collin's Dictionary of Mathematics. The Princeton Companion to Mathematics is good too.) Be aware, a math dictionary will likely be very bulky, only scratch the surface of math, or both.